# Why can't void parameters exist in functions with more than one argument?

Tags: c++

I "wanted" to use `void` as a placeholder (or overload disambiguator) or even as a shortcut to have functions with `void` return type called before entering a specific function like in the following [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1f1f34e54d3a2a6):

```
int f(void , int)
{
    return 0; 
}

void g()
{
}

int main()
{
    f(g(), 1); 
}
```

Now, this is not a real world problem (I know that I could just call `g()` before calling `f()`) but I was wondering why this is not doable, especially when I can  e.g. explicitly return `void` types i.e. this is legal :

```
void h()
{
    return g(); // this does a return void
}
```

---

### EDIT

To explain the rationale behind asking this, I first thought that according to C legacy, `void` would be an **incomplete** type, so incomplete types cannot appear as function parameters, unlike pointers to incomplete types and hence the `void*` commonality. Now this would explain `void` as a "special case" signal for "no parameters" but after C++11 the Standard reads (**3.9 [basic.types]**) :

> 10. A type is a literal type if it is:
>
>     - void; or
>     - a scalar type; or
>         ....

**Being a literal type**, I can't find elsewhere any rationale that would exclude void from candidate types for function parameters, neither the equivalent of old C's (prior to C11) "`void` is not a type". Now, my search may be lacking the required depth which is what I try to compensate for in  this Q

Comment: `void` means there's _no parameter_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ whyyy? In C++ it's preffered to use an empty parameter list to denote "no parameters" right?

Comment: @LorahAttkins You can use it if there is no parameters at all. If you have at least one parameter (like your int), you cannot use it. See my answer.

Comment: @LorahAttkins See the footnote in my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza maybe the edit clarifies my train of thoughts

Comment: @Aracthor Yes, that's a known fact, I'm looking for a rationale behind this though, check the edit

Comment: *"I can't find elsewhere any rationale that would exclude void from candidate types for function parameters"*.  I myself have wished for a costless variable type to typedef out so it was void in a release build but non-void elsewhere.  But a void parameter would posit the existence of void variables.  That's a big semantic space to define for old practically driven languages...what's the address of a void variable, etc.  C and C++ aren't mathematical abstractions to fit all what's possible with a [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type).  Asking "why" will just get you history.

Comment: @HostileFork That's exactly the type of argument I was looking for. And yes, `bottom` and Haskell notation were sort of the reason behind me asking this (but didn't want to mention it to avoid "implementing `maybe` in C++" type of answers). Please write this down in an answer

Comment: Arguments are not answers. This is a Q&A, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've wanted a void argument type in order to have a parameter that is zero-cost in release builds:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
    typedef DebugTracker* Foo;
#else
    typedef void Foo;
#endif

int SomeFunction(Foo foo, ...) {
    ...
}
```

> I can't find elsewhere any rationale that would exclude void from candidate types for function parameters

@juanchopanza has pointed out one thing, which is that C++ inherited C's `f(void)` meaning a function that takes no arguments.  That being so, C++ still could have the feature but make void parameters act as if they had a default value of nothing...so having such a default if they were at the end of argument lists.

In language-design space, it's always easy to think of the case you have in mind and say "why not?".  And if you look at something like [libffi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libffi) then it seems like prohibiting void for arguments makes the system less "pure".  There's a count of bytes for each argument, how hard would it be to allow 0?

But there are questions to answer.

If void parameters are possible, then that posits the existence of void variables.  How does a void variable act?  What's its address?  If you can't take the address of a void variable, how does that impact the compiler...the linker...what's going to happen with name-mangling, etc.

I don't know enough to tell you if the pretzel of the existing C and C++ standard can be untwisted in a way that void parameters do more good than harm.  It would be an interesting study to take a compiler and some large body of code and think through the details.  I upvoted the question as reasonable to ask, but also voted to close as primarily opinion-based, so... that's my 0.02.

Answer (score 3):

A `void` parameter means the function has *no* parameters<sup>*</sup>. It wouldn't make much sense for a function with no parameters to have some parameters.

---

<sup>* This is inherited from C (and presumably kept for compatibility with that language), where a function declared without a parameter list is a function that can take any number of parameters of any type. In C++, such a function would have no parameters, removing the need to use `void` parameters.</sup>

Comment: what if one of the parameters was the return of a `void` return value as in the example?

Comment: @LorahAttkins That doesn't make sense. A *parameter* is not the same as an *argument*.

Comment: And you cannot have an *argument* of type `void`, ever. Even though you can have expressions of that type, they can only be used in limited ways. Passing them to another function as an argument is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The only real problem here is your function prototype:

int f(void , int)

You cannot give a `void` as a parameter. You can set it as a return value, meaning "this function returns nothing", or you can give it as only parameter, like this:

```
int f(void)
```

It would means "this function takes no parameter", but not as a parameter.

But to give a parameter of `void` type would mean you could declare a `void` variable and give it to your function, which would have no sense.

In your sample:

```
void h()
{
    return g(); // this does a return void
}
```

This does **not** a return void. This does return nothing. This is as legal as:

```
void h()
{
    return;
}
```

So here, you can clearly see `void` is just a meaning of nothing.

Try to use functions returning void as arguments, like you did:

```
f(g(), 1);
```

Should be avoided as much as possible.